# "Object Exit" feauture appears when trying to connect a UIButton to the code

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uibutton

When I try to connect my button to the code,

[image]

What is that "Object Exit", how can I make this connection an Outlet (as the above "Connection" line is not clickable and why does this pop up?

Answer (score 4):

This is most likely happening because you do not have the correct `ViewController` or `View` selected in the `Assistant Editor`.

On the right where you have code, check if you have `Automatic` selected and not `Manual`.

It is either this or that view controllers custom class is not correct or left empty in the `Storyboard`.

Since you have a custom `UIView` inside of a `Storyboard` here is a video that explains how to do it, basically you add the method in the `UIView` subclass and link it from the `UIView` subclass back to the storyboard and it should work

https://dzwonsemrish7.cloudfront.net/items/3I083c0u3w35420l110u/Screen%20Recording%202018-04-20%20at%2004.04%20PM.mov

Comment: yes, the first thing to check was if Automatic selected or not

Comment: Is this from a storyboard? If so tap the view controller and in the Utilities panel (right most panel) tap the 3rd icon and make sure Custom Class is inputted and is not empty, where it says UIViewController in gray if nothing is typed in...

Comment: look, I have a view in my view controller, I created a separate UIView file and assigned this class to my view.
Now, I want to connect the buttons located in my view to that new file code. And this problem appears

Comment: Check the updated answer above and let me know if it worked for you!

Answer (score 0):

1) This popup is just settings how the `@IBAction` will look. So just type the name and the connect should be enable. It is name of `@IBAction` function what will be created.

2) "Object Exit" is used in navigation stack. You can outlet action from this button to previous view controller in storyboard and it is used for dismissal, usually.
The outlet @IBAction func should has this signature

```
@IBAction func someActionName(segue: UIStoryboardSegue) { ... }
```